# How to prevent child from one element to be on top of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

(Okay, I know the questions probably sounds rancid bad, so someone edit if they they know how to reformulate it).

So, basically I have this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lunability/TWdD2/)

And as you can probably see, I'm trying to re-create a basic windows 7 aero effect (curiosity, fun, learning, etc nothing big), but I stumbled into a few problems.
 (I will explain only vaguely, since you can see it on the fiddle and otherwise it would be a textathon)

- The text is stuck on top of the parent's(div) parent(div) element.
- The text somehow *leaks* out of the duplicate element(div), even thought it doesn't from the original.

I know this all sounds odd, but you'll probably best see it on the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lunability/TWdD2/).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you're having is stemming from this:

```
$(container).find('*').each(function() {
  var e_clone = $(this).clone(false).appendTo(processor);
  // etc etc
});
```

By using the * selector then running .each you are cloning more markup into #processor than I think you might have intended to. You get two copies of `span.lol` in there because first it clones `#box` (including all its children) and then on the next iteration through the each it copies over `span.lol` on it own.

As for the "leaking" of text out of the parent, it *does* happen in the original... at least that's what I see in Chrome if I comment out the call to `glass('#container', '#processor')`.

Comment: Well, I fixed the spilling problem. For some reason, the text still remains on top, and it's not because of multiple duplicates. I changed the code a little (it's in a debugging stage, only copying the single box and it's children, but the white, sharp, text still remains on top)

Comment: The sharper white text is not on actually on top of the Z-order, take a look at this: http://imgur.com/J8lDQ

Comment: On the first iteration of the .each, you copy .boxblur and it child to #processor via .clone(). But on that iteration of the each, this just refers to .boxblur so your color and text-shadow changes are not applied to that copy of .lol.